# remove stack in fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, fragment

each time when I open a fragment, it will be added to the stack.
So, the back button returns to me according to the stack.

I think I have to delete the stack each time I open a fragment.

if so how can I do that?
here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;

    LinearLayout firstColumn,secondColumn,thirdColumn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        firstColumn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.first_column);
        secondColumn = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.second_column);

        firstColumn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container_frame_layout, new FirstFragment());

                    transaction.commit();

            }
        });

        secondColumn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container_frame_layout, new SecondFragment());

                transaction.commit();
            }
        });



    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack() will return back according to the stack. below code will help you.

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }else 
            super.onBackPressed();
}
```